# Laravel Eloquent: Complex Many-to-Many Relationship with Default Values for Missing Relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I'm facing a complex problem in Laravel concerning Eloquent relationships. I'd appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Here's the structure of my tables:

Tables:

- `albums`: `id`, `name`
- `photos`: `id`, `name`
- `layouts`: `id`, `name`
- `album_photo`: `album_id`, `photo_id`
- `album_photo_layout`: `album_id`, `photo_id`, `layout_id`, `visibility`

Relationships:

- An album can have multiple photos (many-to-many relation between `albums` and `photos` with a pivot table `album_photo`).
- A photo can belong to multiple albums.
- Each photo in each album can have multiple layouts with unique visibility settings (three-way many-to-many relation between `albums`, `photos`, and `layouts` with a pivot table `album_photo_layout`).

What I'm trying to achieve is to get all albums, with all photos in each album, and all possible layouts for each photo. If a certain layout is not linked with a photo for a specific album, I want it to be added with a default visibility value.

Here is my current approach:

```php
$album->load([
    'photos.layouts' => fn($query) => $query->where('album_id', $album->id)
]);
```

But this doesn't include layouts that haven't been linked with a photo for a specific album. These missing layouts should be included with a default `visibility` value.

I've tried to address this using `whenLoaded()` in the resource, but without success. It returns `null` for missing layouts and doesn't meet my requirements.

Ideally, I want a solution that adheres to the Eloquent ORM principles, without resorting to raw SQL queries.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand it right, but shouldn't you use relation to `album_photo` table in `album_photo_layout` instead of `album_id` and `photo_id`?

Comment: I really don't get the `missing layouts` part. Could you elaborate further? Also, Laravel provide [withDefault](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#default-models) method, which can be used to specify default model, if that's what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change things up a bit.

```
Album:
- id
- name
- hasMany(AlbumPhoto)
```

```
Photo:
- id
- name
- hasMany(AlbumPhoto)
```

```
Layout
- id
- name
- hasMany(AlbumPhotoLayout)
```

```
AlbumPhoto
- id
- belongsTo(Photo)
- belongsTo(Album)
- hasMany(AlbumPhotoLayout)
```

```
AlbumPhotoLayout
- id
- belongsTo(AlbumPhoto)
- belongsTo(Layout)
```

What you are looking for is `Album::with('albumPhoto.albumPhotoLayout');`

I find it useful in many cases to model pivots as models. Also, you can find a middle ground by defining [`Pivot` classes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models). Actually, `AlbumPhoto` and `AlbumPhotoLayouts` can extend `Pivot` instead of `Model`.